# Math How many boxes can fit in area

Tags: math

lets say I have a viewport with a width of 1000px

And in the viewport I have 3 boxes placed horizontally along the viewport.

Each box is 500px. Now normally it would be `viewport_width / box_width` which would yield `2`

How ever, if you were to move the first box slightly to the left, out of the viewport, the 3rd box would be slightly visible on the right hand side.

What equasion would i need to use to figure out the maximum number of boxes which can be visible in the defined viewport (assume all boxes are the same width)

Thanks

Comment: Given your specification, you've already given the answer, 3.

Comment: my code has to assume the viewport width will change constantly, so i need to compute it on the fly

Comment: What else changes?  Do you need a general formula for any viewport, box, # of boxes?

Comment: yea just a general formula which assumes that viewport size can change, box numbers can change and box width can change. all boxes will be same width however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you already have it figured out. Since there can only ever be 1 partial box on either end, the maximum number of visible boxes should be `(viewport_width / box_width) + 1`

To take into account Will's (correct) caveat:

`ceil((viewport_width/box_width) + 1))`

Edit: convinced myself that ceil is in fact the correct choice

Comment: If the OP is asking for a general formula (not clear), how about the case of viewport_width = 11, box_width = 3?  Five boxes can be visible at once. (with 1, 3, 3, 3, 1 'columns' visible from the boxes).

Comment: i used this together with ceiling the value in ( ) and it works perfectly.

Comment: ...but given that (with ceiling), viewport_width = 10, box_width = 3 would give 5 which is incorrect.

Comment: True, using round would make sense as kniteli wrote:)

Comment: @Ozzy - hmm, I'm not convinced.  I'm sure that this will still give incorrect results.  How about with vpw 11 and bw 2?  Gives 7, answer should be 6.

Comment: @Will The correct answer is indeed 7, [built as 1100px with 200px boxes](http://imgur.com/ZqSV3) Edit: I apologize profusely for those colors.

Comment: @kniteli - try the same with 2px boxes - or with the 200px boxes but only being able to scroll in increments of 100px (i.e. a zooomed in version of 11px / 2px).

Comment: @Will Yeah, mathematically it will always work, but as a single pixel is indivisible there is a special exception that needs to be handled in that case, whether your box is 200px or 2px.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same math, really. You seem to be thinking of fractional boxes as if being able to see 50% of box A, 100% of box B, and 50% of box C is more than two boxes, total, but it's not. The equation is unchanged.